# coset and Lagrange's theorem problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that if $G$ is a finite group, the index of $Z(G)$ cannot be prime.

First of all, I'm not sure what does $Z(G)$ mean. Can somebody tell me what does this symbol mean and how to solve this problem ? Thanks.

Comment: $Z(G)$ is common notation for the center of the group, those elements that commute with everything.

Comment: Did you try googling? [Center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_(group_theory)) is the first result. Also, if you look under examples on the wikipedia page, it says that if $G / Z(G) $ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian, hence $G=Z(G)$. If you can prove this statement, you have the above result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would be helpful for you to check that :

> If $G/Z(G)$ is a cyclic group then $G$ is abelian.

Suppose for some prime $p$, $|G/Z(G)|=p$ then $G$ is abelian..

So, $Z(G)=G$ and then, $|G/Z(G)|=1$

please note that $1$ is neither prime nor composite :)

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $Z(G)$ has prime index, say $p$. Then we have disjoint cosets $$Z(G), aZ(G), \ldots, a^{p-1}Z(G)$$ whose union is $G$ for some $a \in G$. Of course, this means that if $b \in G$, then $b = a^k g$ for some $g \in Z(G)$, $k < p$. But then, note that $$ab = a a^k g = a^k a g = a^k g a = ba.$$ This is true for any $b \in G$. So $a \in Z(G)$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: How did you get the first step? "We have disjoint cosets Z(G), aZ(G)..."

Comment: The center is always a normal subgroup. Take the quotient.